# Check if a variable is nan with Python

Tags: python

I want to check if a variable is `nan` with Python.

I have a working method `value != value` gives `True` if `value` is an `nan`. However, it is ugly and not so readable. Plus, sonarcloud considers it as a bug for the reason "identical expressions should not be used on both sides of a binary operator".

Do you have a better/elegant solution? Thanks.

```
import math
import numpy as np

v1 = float('nan')
v2 = math.nan
v3 = np.nan

def check_nan(value) -> bool:
    is_nan =  value != value
    return is_nan

v1_is_nan = check_nan(value=v1)
v2_is_nan = check_nan(value=v2)
v3_is_nan = check_nan(value=v3)

print(v1_is_nan)  # printed True
print(v2_is_nan)  # printed True
print(v3_is_nan)  # printed True
```

Comment: The code as provided doesn't really look like real actual code from a project. Who would use the name `check_nan_ugly_method` in actual code?

Comment: @Peilonrayz this is an example code, I have simplified my actual project code to focus on my question. Why do you need my actual project code?

Comment: Please read the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), specifically the section "Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or hypothetical code?" Currently the, unhelpful, answer "use better function names" can be a legitimate answer because you chose to change your code to be worse than I assume it is.

Comment: @Peilonrayz thanks for your info. I did not know this.

Comment: @aura You should edit your question.

Comment: What do you expect this will do? `is_nan =  value != value`

Comment: Thank you, I have started a vote to reopen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods for this already exist, particularly because of the weird properties of NaNs. One of them can be found in the `math` library, [`math.isnan`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan) and `numpy` already has a method implemented for this as well, [`numpy.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html). They both deal with all three kinds of NaNs shown in your code (but the `numpy` version is vectorized):

```
import math
import numpy as np

list(map(math.isnan, [float("nan"), math.nan, np.nan]))
# [True, True, True]

np.isnan([float("nan"), math.nan, np.nan]) 
# array([ True,  True,  True])
```

If you are using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/), [`pandas.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) is also interesting because it considers `None` and `pandas.NaT` (Not a Time) as missing values as well:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.isna([float("nan"), math.nan, np.nan, None, pd.NaT])
# array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

---

Your code has a potential flaw, it does not return `True` only for NaNs (although it does return `True` for all NaNs), but for all objects which are not equal to themselves. In particular, it will think any instance of this class is NaN (probably true, but not necessarily):

```
class A:
    def __equal__(self, other):
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO your function is correct and readable as it is.
If I see something like `x != x` in any language my mind jumps immediately to NaN,
regardless of the type.
So if you have something like a missing string or date or whatever, this test still makes sense.

Regarding the report from sonarsource. It is always helpful to read the rationale behind a rule. If you look [here](https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/RSPEC-1764)
there are nice examples why this rule generally makes sense. I don't think this applies in your case and you can ignore it.

Some nitpicks:

1. I would directly return without creating a temporary. The same is true for printing.
2. There are two spaces after is_nan =
3. Your functions are not in a class and are really functions. Even if they were methods it would be very redundant to add it. Why don't you just call it `is_nan`?

```
import math
import numpy as np

v1 = float('nan')
v2 = math.nan
v3 = np.nan

def is_nan(value) -> bool:
    return value != value

print(is_nan(v1))
print(is_nan(v2))
print(is_nan(v3))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I like your idea about renaming the function. However, I still think `x==x` is not so readable for checking `nan`.